# What is the different between message-id and network-message-id in Exchange

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, microsoft365

currently I'm facing the problems to explain this two term, Message-Id and X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id in Microsoft Exchange?
Based on the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/message-tracking?view=exchserver-2019) explanation I still not understand

**message-id**

The value of the Message-Id: header field in the message header. If the Message-Id: header field doesn't exist or is blank, Exchange assigns an arbitrary value. This value is constant for the lifetime of the message. For messages created in Exchange, the value is in the format GUID@ServerFQDN, including the angle brackets (< >). For example, 4867a3d78a50438bad95c0f6d072fca5@mailbox01.contoso.com. Other messaging systems may use different syntax or values.

**network-message-id**
A unique message ID value that persists across copies of the message that may be created due to bifurcation or distribution group expansion. An example value is 1341ac7b13fb42ab4d4408cf7f55890f.

Answer (score 0):

**Message-ID** seems to be an identifier of the message which is generated at the sender side according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID). This id can be deleted.
The **network-message-id** seems to be something created only within exchange which stays unique across message modifications at exchange side see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/message-tracking?view=exchserver-2019).